# No time clock at work place

Tags: work-time

We have a new supervisor and he is requiring that we utilize a time clock. The problem is there is no time clock at more than one of the sites I work at. Can he require that we drive from the site that has no time clock to a site that does for lunch and break times?

Comment: Have you asked if a time clock can be installed at the site? Otherwise, you'd basically be 'on-the-clock' until you get to the other place, right?

Comment: Yes, I am on the clock, but having to travel from one site to another for morning break, lunch break and afternoon break is costing me in gas that I am not being compensated for. Hardly seems fair that I need to travel to clock in and out 5 times in one day especially when break times are paid breaks.

Comment: If you're traveling for work (not to and from work, but during your job), then you should be compensated for that. If you're not.. then that's something worth enquiring about with your employer too.

Comment: Gad, the last time I had to use a timeclock was when I was flipping burgers in college.  Sounds like your supervisor just got his McDiploma last week.  Send the above paragraph to your manager and ask for instructions.  This isn't (supposed to be) your problem.

Comment: @WesleyLong some companies can be... sticklers as far as monitoring time-sheet issues, unfortunately. This can be exasperated if you have a contract that stipulates only X# of hours and Y# of employees will be paid for (as in a temp service)

Comment: Do you have a union?

Comment: VTC as a legal question. A US employer can require virtually anything as long as he's paying you for your time and not violating employment law. What your options are in this specific situation is something to discuss with HR, the state labor department, a lawyer or a union rep.

Comment: If you have lunch break from 12:00 to 12:30 and it takes half an hour to drive to the clock, you'll have to leave work at 11:30, clock out at 12:00, have your break, clock in at 12:30 and be back at your workplace at 13:00. Once your supervisor (or his manager) understands this, the rule will change :-)

Answer (score 6):

I am going to go by personal experience on this one. Your mileage may vary.

There are 2 non "install a time-clock" solutions to this dilemma:

**Solution 1)** have time cards that are filled out and approved by someone on the worksite (preferably whoever's in charge). *Problem:* time cards can get lost, are difficult to track, and, ultimately may not accurately tell how long you were there if it takes awhile to track down someone to sign off on your start/ end times. *Cost:* negligible (time to make the initial form + printing costs, getting the forms out to the workers or having them print them up themselves)

**Solution 2)** software. There's various software for the smartphones that can track a person's work day, include breaks. Each person would be given a unique code, and the manager would also have to input his code as well to verify. *Problem:* phone may die because of use, get lost, stolen, misplaced - but if you have a computer that has an emulator, simply log onto it. *Cost:* free to medium (per user + monthly fee, generally)

a quick google search of "Timeclock app" will come up with quite a few results

Answer (score 5):

Just ask your supervisor how to do it, and abide by his answer.

Comment: Just make clear that your working time starts when you clock in and finishes when you clock out. Which is just common sense, so if the clock is far away from your workplace the company is just hurting itself.